# How would I update marker position in google map when user current Position is changed?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want whenever my current location is changed than marker position is also update  and it appear in it's next new location in map .?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) and update your `MapView` in the `onLocationChanged` callback

> ```
> abstract void     onLocationChanged(Location location)
> ```
>
> Called when the location has changed.

There's a topic in the dev guide about this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Comment: hi i have applied all the methods in my code it gives me current position in first me only whenever i changed my position the marker in google is not update plz  i really nead this plz help

Comment: You then need to use the `Location` object in the callback to update the location of your `OverLayItem`. For an example on how to do it, see the tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Answer (score 2):

You simply use MyLocationOverlay: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html

No need to listen to GPS as MyLocationOverlay manages this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

For the LocationManager class:

To get one update you can use [getLastKnownLocation(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29)

or requestLocationUpdates(long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria criteria, PendingIntent intent) if you want periodical updates.

If you aren't using LocationManager, please specify what you're trying to do :)

Hope it works, and good luck!

Comment: hi i have applied all the methods in my code it gives me current position in first me only whenever i changed my position the marker in google is not update plz i really nead this plz hel